# Explicite upper bound for the smallest primitive root?

Tags: reference-request, primitive-roots

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) Wikipedia article some upper bounds for the smallest primitive root $g$ modulo a prime $p$ are given, but the first is implicite (what is the constant $C$ depending on $\epsilon$) and the other is only proven for ridiculous large primes.

> What is the best known unconiditionally proven explicite upper bound that holds from a reasonably large prime on, say for $p\ge 10^6$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jana Pretorius posted a preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.11061.pdf) that contains Theorem 2: the least primitive root modulo $p$ is less than $p^{0.68}$ for all primes $p$. (Note that one cannot do too much better with this exact shape of statement, since $2\approx 3^{0.631}$.) It might be possible to do better using Theorem 3 of [this paper of McGown and Trudgian](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.12373.pdf), although probably not since Pretorius acknowledges McGown and Trudgian in their preprint, suggesting that they wouldn't have produced redundant results.

Comment: Wow, very nice (+1 and accept)